# Add Product ID in the cart URL in Woocommerce

Tags: function, url, woocommerce, product, cart

I'd like to add the product ID to the cart URL in order to track it as a custom event.

We already achieve this for the checkout Thank you page with the following function:

```
function webroom_add_prduct_id_in_order_url($return_url,$order){

    //create empty array to store url parameters in 
    $sku_list = array();

    // retrive products in order
    foreach($order->get_items() as $key => $item){
        $product = wc_get_product($item['product_id']);
        //get sku of each product and insert it in array 
        
        $sku_list['product_id_'.$item['product_id']] = $product->get_id();
    }
    
    //build query strings out of the SKU array
    $url_extension = http_build_query($sku_list);
    
    //append our strings to original url
    $modified_url = $return_url.'&'.$url_extension;
    
    return $modified_url;
}
```

How can we get the same behaviour but for the cart page URLs?

Comment: Please add desired output you expected.

Comment: When a product is added to the cart I'd like to return the product's ID in the URL.

i.e: mydomain.com/cart/{product-id}